# sed insert "//"

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Hopefully a simple one here - I'm trying to insert // at a line that I grep to hash out the php option

```
grep user@ file | sed -i 's/"//"/user'
```

I'm not sure how to do the character "//" in a sed? I'm also thinking about a sed command to has out all the cron jobs by add an # at the start of each cron

Thanks

Comment: `sed -i` doesn't really make sense when reading from standard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you want to add `//` at the beginning of the line:

```
sed -i '/user@/ s_^_//_' file
```

(try without `-i` first)

If you mean something else, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` can use delimiters other than `/`:

```
sed -i '/user@/s|^|//|' file
```

Comment: `s` is the substitution operator in `sed`. This command applies the substitution "// for ^" (i.e., add '//' to the beginning) for each line containing "user@".

Answer (score 1):

Another way of accomplishing it would be to:

```
sed 's|user@|//&|' file.php
```

It uses `|` as the delimiter as well as `&` as a matched pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I found one more option to make it work!!!

```
sed -i '/user@/s/^/\/\//' file
```